# How to get the number of pages of a google doc using google docs api?

Tags: node.js, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am executing the below code and getting the json response successfully but I don't see any information about total number of pages of the doc.

```
const baseUrl = `https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/${doc_id}`
const response = await googleReq(baseUrl, ctx.accessToken).then(res => {
   let data = res.json()
   return data
}).catch(err => console.log(err))

const googleReq = (url, token) => {
    if (!token) return new Error("No accessToken")
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
}
```

Please let me know how to get the number of pages.

Comment: What language do you want to use? I couldn't understand about it from your tags in your question. From your script, I thought that you might be using Javascript or Node.js using node-fetch
. But that is my guess. I apologize for this.

Comment: You can only get manual page breaks, not the number of pages, from the API. If you check out the [Document resource documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents) you can see there is no returned data on the number of pages the document takes up.

Comment: @Tanaike I am using Node.js

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I see the pageBreak in the documentation but the response json data doesn't have any pageBreak information.

Comment: A pagebreak is a manual pagebreak, it only shows up when you literally force a page break (pressing Ctrl+enter inside the doc online). The auto page-breaks aren't returned.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the tag.